# how Run command line exe and use in it in windows command prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I have a exe tool name imgConv.exe then i open it in windows command line and try to use it's functionality s. but prompt said "no any internal or external command"

how can i install it and use its features in command prompt?

Comment: Add the appropriate directory to your `PATH`

Comment: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/q/284342)

Comment: I setup environment verifiable my exe to cmd but it din't work...